# How to find the distribution of $Y = 2X$ if $X$ is a continuous random variable.

Tags: probability

**Problem:** I want to find the distribution of $Y = 2X$ if $X$ is a continuous random variable.

**My answer:** If $f(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$, then the probability density function, $g(y)$, of $Y = 2X$ I thought would be

$$
g(y) = f\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)
$$

because when $Y = 50$, say, we should have the same density as when $X = 25$.

But on the other hand the cumulative distribution

$$
G(Y) = P[Y \leq y] = P\left[X \leq \frac{y}{2}\right] = F\left(\frac{y}{2}\right).
$$

This gives us that $g(y) = G^{\prime}(y) = \frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)$ by the chain rule.

**Question:** Why don't the two derivations agree? Do I have to appeal to the cumulative distribution of $X$ for some reason?  I mean what did I miss in the first derivation using just $f(x)$ to miss the extra factor of $1/2$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: In your first derivation, it doesn't integrate to $1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because stretching the PDF of X by a factor of 2 doubles the area under the graph, which means it's not a PDF anymore (recall that a valid PDF has to integrate to 1). So you have to normalise by dividing by 2.